# React Native compile error @react-native-firebase_app module

Tags: react-native

I can't compile react native app because of error as below:
Which file do I have to add this mentioned line as below `android.buildFeatures.buildConfig true` ?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':@react-native-firebase_app'.

> defaultConfig contains custom BuildConfig fields, but the feature is disabled.
> To enable the feature, add the following to your module-level build.gradle:
> `android.buildFeatures.buildConfig true`

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.